# MySQL Multiple Binary Log Destinations

Tags: mysql, binary-log

I know in Oracle it is possible to specify up to 10 archive log destinations. Does anyone know if it is possible to specify multiple, concurrent locations for the MySQL Binary Log? (And no, I'm not implying that MySQL would have this since they are now owned by Oracle... ;-) )

Looking for confirmation on this. I have tested several options for possibly getting  this to happen without success. I have also searched and cannot find anything on the topic. From what I have seen, I believe the answer is "No".

I'm not looking for any convoluted solutions (scripts,etc.) to make this happen outside MySQL -- I just need to know if MySQL has any sort of built in functionality to do it.

This is for 5.0.77 as included in RHEL 5.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your immediate question, MySQL does not provide such mechanisms for storing binary logs in multiple locations. You should look into setting up multiple distribution masters.

This would require setting up a replication Slave with two criteria

- Every DB has BLACKHOLE tables (except information_schema and mysql)
- Binary Logging is Enabled

If you set up multiple slave likes this within the same DB server, just have each distribution master save its binary logs to distinct locations.

[This is not a new concept. I answered a question on StackOverflow on setting this up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273043/mysql-in-star-topology/5781504#5781504).

Answer (score 0):

May be you want a slave db?

Its the same, recieve master binary log from 'master' and play it on local mysql-server.

So some kind of multiple binlog ;)